# How to solve the risk Unreleased Resource: Unmanaged Object(unmanaged_object) via fortify

Tags: c#, fortify

These days, I have a simple C# project which has security risks by the scanning report via fortify. This project is based on the .NET Windows form application. The name of this risk is `Unreleased Resource: Unmanaged Object(unmanaged_object)`.

For example, if I want to construct label controller by dropping controller figures on the toolbox into the form design. Then modify the font size would change the code in `Form1.Designer` automatically. For example, it would generates the following code:

`this.label1.font = new System.Drawing.Font(...)`

The key is we declare a Font object via the constructor `System.Drawing.Font(...)`. But we don't dispose this object? So, how do we avoid this risk?

p.s., if we change the code at the area which is generated by visual studio in `Form1.Designer` file. Then we even can not edit the form anymore~ (Because any setting of controllers (e.g. change the `foreColor` property of a bottom) would change the code in this part of the file).

Also, we do not want create every controllers in the initialization method. Does anybody has a good way to solve this problem? Thank you very much!!

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Fortify doesn't want you to depend on the GC.  If I use a using statement, then the font goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You could call:

```
 this.label1.font.Dispose();
```

explictly in your form's FormClosed event. You'll have to do it for every Font object you have created in the form.

Not very pretty though... It's usually easier to just let it get finalized by the GC (unless you're making LOTS of font objects), but Fortify clearly has rules about explicit disposal here.